# Jquery loaded image not reacting on class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a html page I load manual 3 images in a div. 
By jquery I load all images from a dir in the same div.

By clicking on the image the manual added react on the class and insert them self in a textbox (a contenteditable div)

The jquery added will not react at all.

All code of the images is the same.(f12)

I guess it's something with time of load. but can anybody help me with this.

My code (script)

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        loadicon('#mydiv', "../images/ico", "25px", "25px");
        $('.InsertEmo').click(function () {
            var img = " <img src=\"" + $(this).attr('src') + "\" width=\"" + $(this).attr('width') + "\" height=\"" + $(this).attr('height') + "\" /> ";
            $('#divMessage').html($('#divMessage').html() + " " + img + " ");
        });
    });

    function loadicon(tab, dir, imgWidth, imgHeight) {

        var fileextension = [".gif", ".png", ".jpg", ".ico"];
        var filename;

        $.ajax({
            //This will retrieve the contents of the folder if the folder is configured as 'browsable'
            url: dir,
            success: function (data) {
                //Lsit all png file names in the page
                $(data).find("a:contains(" + (fileextension[0]) + "), a:contains(" + (fileextension[1]) + "), a:contains(" + (fileextension[2]) + "), a:contains(" + (fileextension[3]) + ")").each(function () {
                    filename = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http:///", "");
                    $(tab).append($("<img type='image' src=" + "../" + filename + " width=\"" + imgWidth + "\" height=\"" + imgHeight + "\" class='InsertEmo' />"));
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Mycode HTML

```
    <div class="messageBar" style="min-height: 30px; width:800px;">
        <div id="divMessage" contenteditable="true" class="textbox single-line" style="float:left; border: 1px solid black; width: 300px "></div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="mydiv">
        <img type="image" src="../Images/checkmark.ico" width="25px" height="25px" class="InsertEmo" />
        <img type="image" src="../Images/folder.ico" width="25px" height="25px" class="InsertEmo" />
        <img type="image" src="../Images/skype.ico" width="25px" height="25px" class="InsertEmo" />
    </div>
```

Thanx Dinand

Comment: After Ajax success and appending data you have to call `$('.InsertEmo').click(function ());`again on your dom.

Comment: Your problem is that the click event is not fired ? try to change your listener to `$('#mydiv').on('click', '.InsertEmo', function () {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to delegate your click event:

```
$('#mydiv').on('click', '.InsertEmo', function () {
            var img = " <img src=\"" + $(this).attr('src') + "\" width=\"" + $(this).attr('width') + "\" height=\"" + $(this).attr('height') + "\" /> ";
            $('#divMessage').html($('#divMessage').html() + " " + img + " ");
        });
```

That way dynamically addded elements will get the event delegated from its parent element.

Comment: Wow... Great men (and so fast)... This did the trick.. perfect solution. Thanx

Comment: No problem, glad that i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

The first three images got the handler, because you're binding it after page load.
But then the reloaded images are not created, so the selector will not include them.
You have to bind the click handler for every created image again:

```
   var $image = $("<img type='image' src=" + "../" + filename + " width=\"" + imgWidth + "\" height=\"" + imgHeight + "\" class='InsertEmo' />");

   $image.click(function () {
       var img = " <img src=\"" + $(this).attr('src') + "\" width=\"" + $(this).attr('width') + "\" height=\"" + $(this).attr('height') + "\" /> ";
        $('#divMessage').html($('#divMessage').html() + " " + img + " ");
    });

   $(tab).append($image);
```